# Why I can not get cookies from requests.get

Tags: django, cookies, python-requests

I have this in my `views.py` (Django 1.7)

```
class Info(View):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'command.html', {'result': request.META.items()})
```

and I tried to use requests.get to get cookies, like this:

```
print(requests.get(r'http://127.0.0.1:8000/info/').cookies.items())
```

But, there was no cookie, I only got an empty list, how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to:

1. Set the cookie into the `Response` object

   ```
   response = render(request, 'command.html', {'result': request.META.items()})
   response.set_cookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value')
   return response
   ```
2. Search for the cookie inside `request.COOKIES`

   ```
   if 'cookie_name' in request.COOKIES:
       cookie_value = request.COOKIES['cookie_name']
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
requests.get(r'http://127.0.0.1:8000/info/').cookies.items())
```

This looks ok to me. If it returns an empty list, it means that your view is not setting any cookies.

By default, Django only sets the session cookie when the session has been modified. See the Django docs on [when sessions are saved](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved) for more information.